# Problem in Vertical Menu With Navigation in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

we would like to know, How to create Vertical Navigation Menu in Wordpress. I have created the Simple Menu in wordpress.
We want to implement  this structure in Menu.

```
   CategoryName(without hyperlink)
         echo Posts on this category(With URL)
               SubcategoryName(URL using #)
                    echo Posts on this category(With URL)
```

please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

ROD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>` [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories) or you have to do two loops, one to find all the categories and one the find the posts under each category.

Comment: Please give an idea for using loop for same function. I am a beginner.